# Beamer: \begin{frame} + minted package for syntax highlighting

Tags: beamer, environments, minted, fragile

I am trying to define a .sty file to help adding slides with code samples in my presentations. The *minted* package is a nice-looking solution for adding syntax-highlighting, but I can't get it to work together with a custom environment using \begin{frame}.

*my beamerthemetheme.sty file is defined as below:*

```
\usepackage{minted}
\newenvironment{Sli}[1]{  
\begin{frame}[fragile]
{}
 #1
\end{frame}
}%
```

my main.tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} %. Aspect Ratio 16:9
\usetheme{theme}

\begin{document}
\Sli{
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np
\end{minted}
}
\end{document}
```

But it is impossible to get the \Sli command working together with minted.

When written as defined above I get a **Runaway argument?** error. I've tried moving things around and small changes and the error changes but I still can't get it working. Curiously, if I use the commands directly without separating it in the `\Sli` command it works:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} %. Aspect Ratio 16:9
\usetheme{theme}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any thoughts on how I can fix the `\Sli` command definition to make it work?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but IMHO, it is not a good practice to wrap `frame`s inside a command or an environment.

Comment: That's a bad idea - in fact doubly so. Hiding a frame behind a custom environment/macro creates more problem than in solves. In many situations, beamer needs to be able to find the verbatim string `\end{frame}` in your code. That's in particular important from fragile frames. There are workaround for this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326787/difficulty-in-creating-macro-newcommand-for-the-beginning-and-end-of-frames-i but they'll just create more problems.

Comment: The second and more important problem: You must not use fragile content like a minted environment in the argument of a macro.