# Defining command for beginning/spliting frame

Tags: beamer

Because of how I use beamer, I would ideally like not to use \begin{frame} and \end{frame} but rather just the command \fr for whenever I start a new frame.

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326879/10753), what I have right now is a combination of \fr and \nofr like so:

```
  \newcommand{\fr}[1][]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \def\startfrm{\begin{frame}}%
    \else
      \def\startfrm{\begin{frame}[#1]}%
    \fi
    \innerbfrm
  }

  \long\def\innerbfrm#1\nofr{\startfrm#1\end{frame}}
```

I would ideally like to add the following at the beginning of  the definition of \fr:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{no_frame}}{}{\nofr}
\setboolean{no_frame}{false}
```

where no_frame is a boolean which gets set to true at the beginning of the document. This way I should be able to use only \fr instead of \nofr\fr. (One would still need to use one \nofr at the end of document or add it to a suitable hook.)

But whatever I do beamer/latex complain. I have it set up this way for example for quick items with \qitem instead of \begin{enumerate}\item\end{enumerate} so it seems likely it's a beamer issue.

Comment: `\begin{frame}` wants to explicitly see `\end{frame}` in order to determine the frame's content. Hiding it in a macro will not work.

Comment: Instead of obfuscating your code with such macros, maybe use an editor which supports code snippets to quickly add the real syntax?

Comment: I'd rather not, no editor support can ever beat superior syntax (by superior I mean superior for my particular application), especially if very intensive rewritings/refactorings  take place very frequently.

Comment: if you implement such a syntax you are making it much harder to communicate code with other people, so do it only if you think that you never will have to ask a question about beamer on tex.sx or similar in the future.